# ActionSheetPickerClass , iOS

Tags: ios, date, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I am using this class , https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker to choose current date in my application. The problem is that i would also like to choose a time (hour and minutes) with a picker like this. Can anyone help me customize the class or know any other class that does that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used, just saw the source code now. But from here:

```
  _actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:self.selectedDate target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:) origin:sender];
```

You need to define your `datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate` so you need to check what types the `UIDatePickerMode` accepts. So:

```
typedef enum {
    UIDatePickerModeTime,           // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeDate,           // Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)
    UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,    // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer  // Displays hour and minute (e.g. 1 | 53)
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

Select the one you want.